# Mostrar datos de usuario de la BD cuando inicia sesión, php, $_SESSION

Tags: php, mvc, login, session

tengo una función nombreUsuario() que coge el usuario que ha iniciado sesión con php y muestra el parámetro recibido en el login, en este caso el mail, ya que coge el $_SESSION['usuario']. Está función está en el código de UsuarioController.php. Me funciona bien y cuando inicia sesión muestra el mensaje, con el parámetro 'usuario' que corresponde al email. Pero yo quiero que muestre el nombre y apellidos del usuario que están en la base de datos. Está hecho con un modelo vista controlador. Como puedo hacer para coger el nombre y apellidos en vez del email. Muestro código de las partes. muchas gracias.

UsuarioController.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/DB/UsuarioDB.php');

class UsuarioController{

public function login($u, $p){
        $db = new UsuarioDB();
        if($db->login($u, $p)){
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $u;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    
    public function nombreUsuario(){
        return $_SESSION['usuario'];
        
    }
    
    }
```

UsuarioDB.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Usuario.php');

class UsuarioDB{
    
    private $conexion;
    
    public function login($usuario, $password){
        $this->conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario'";
        $stm = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->get_result();
        
        $r = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
        $salt = md5('Sunrise');
        $contra = $salt.$password;
        $pwd = md5($contra);
        
        if($usuario == $r['email'] && $pwd == $r['contrasena']){ 
        //Login OK
        return true;
        } else {
            //Login NO OK
            return false;
        }
    }
    
   }
```

model/Usuario.php

```html
<?php 

class Usuario{
    
    private $_id_usuario;
    private $_nombre;
    private $_apellidos;
    private $_fecha_nacimiento;
    private $_email;
    private $_contrasena;
    private $_telefono;
    private $_ciudad;
    
    public function __construct($id = null, $n = null, $a = null, $f = null, $e = null, $c = null, $t = null, $ci = null){
        $this->setId_usuario($id);
        $this->setNombre($n);
        $this->setApellidos($a);
        $this->setFecha_nacimiento($f);
        $this->setEmail($e);
        $this->setContrasena($c);
        $this->setTelefono($t);
        $this->setCiudad($ci);
        
    }
    
    
    public function getId_usuario()
    {
        return $this->_id_usuario;
    }

    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->_nombre;
    }

    public function getApellidos()
    {
        return $this->_apellidos;
    }

    public function getFecha_nacimiento()
    {
        return $this->_fecha_nacimiento;
    }
    
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->_email;
    }
    
    public function getContrasena()
    {
        return $this->_contrasena;
    }
    
    public function getTelefono()
    {
        return $this->_telefono;
    }
    
    public function getCiudad()
    {
        return $this->_ciudad;
    }
    

    public function setId_usuario($_id_usuario)
    {
        $this->_id_usuario = $_id_usuario;
    }

    public function setNombre($_nombre)
    {
        $this->_nombre = $_nombre;
    }

    public function setApellidos($_apellidos)
    {
        $this->_apellidos = $_apellidos;
    }

    public function setFecha_nacimiento($_fecha_nacimiento)
    {
        $this->_fecha_nacimiento = $_fecha_nacimiento;
    }
    
    public function setEmail($_email)
    {
        $this->_email = $_email;
    }
    
    public function setContrasena($_contrasena)
    {
        $this->_contrasena = $_contrasena;
    }
    
    public function setTelefono($_telefono)
    {
        $this->_telefono = $_telefono;
    }
    
    public function setCiudad($_ciudad)
    {
        $this->_ciudad = $_ciudad;
    }
    
    public function toArray(){
        $obj = [];
        $obj['id_usuario'] = $this->getId_usuario();
        $obj['nombre'] = $this->getNombre();
        $obj['apellidos'] = $this->getApellidos();
        $obj['fecha_nacimiento'] = $this->getFecha_nacimiento();
        $obj['email'] = $this->getEmail();
        $obj['contrasena'] = $this->getContrasena();
        $obj['telefono'] = $this->getTelefono();
        $obj['ciudad'] = $this->getCiudad();
        
        return $obj;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: ¿El usuario ($u) es el correo electrónico?

Comment: sí. @JosueArriola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que tu funcion login(), en lugar de devolver TRUE, te devuelva los datos que necesites. En `UsuarioDB.php` cambia:

```
if($usuario == $r['email'] && $pwd == $r['contrasena']) { 
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Por esto:

```
if($usuario == $r['email'] && $pwd == $r['contrasena']) { 
  return $r;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Entonces, en `UsuarioController.php` podrás cambiar tu funcion login()

```
public function login($u, $p){
  $db = new UsuarioDB();
  $us = $db->login($u, $p);
  if ($us !== false && is_array($us)) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $us['email'];
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $us['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['apellidos'] = $us['apellidos'];
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

No veo que uses las funciones get y set en `model/Usuario.php`. Deberías revisar eso...